# What color are B-Wing squadrons?

Tags: star-wars

What colors are usually associated with B-wings? We've seen in the movies that X-wings usually have red and blue, Y-wings are gold, and A-wings are green. Are there any references in the movies or in the novels that designate what colors B-wing squadrons have? Or if a B-wing pilot gives out their callsign on the comms, what color did they declare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that any of them have a color. Canon has them in [Blade Squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Squadron), based on [the short story of the same name](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Squadron_(short_story)) (doesn't appear to be a retcon since none ever identify a color in RotJ)

[image: B-Wing squadron patch]

Answer (score 1):

It's never mentioned on screen, but according the Wookieepedia's entry on the [Battle of Endor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Endor) there are two different designations.  "Blade Squadron" seems to come from a short story of the same name, while a digital trading card game from 2015 refers to them as "Blue Squadron."